# Issue while Unit Testing ASP.Net Core with Mediatr

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit, mediatr

I am using ASP.Net Core 3.1 Repository Pattern and Unit of Work Using Dapper .
I have use mediator as

```
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
 
namespace TaskManagementApp.Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ApiController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IMediator _mediator;
        protected IMediator Mediator => _mediator ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMediator>();
    }
}
```

i am facing issue how can i write unit test to set value for HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService

here is my controller to be unit tested

```
namespace OneCubeCoaching.API.WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ContactController : BaseApiController
    {
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet("GetAll")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return Ok(await Mediator.Send(new GetAllClientQuery()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual  issue/problem? Not seeing a problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just depend on IMediator in the constructor.

Assuming your code you meant `ApiController` was in fact `BaseApiController` (per your second code segment) something like this will work:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class BaseApiController : ControllerBase
{
    protected ApiController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    protected IMediator {get; private set;}
}
```

Then your `ContactController` can pass IMediator to base:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ContactController : BaseApiController
{
    public ContactController (IMediator mediator) 
        :base(mediator)

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("GetAll")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return Ok(await Mediator.Send(new GetAllClientQuery()));
    }
}
```

Now, you can Mock IMediator as you normally would.